# Trying to make something like search with python

Tags: python

The code works and I dont have any idea how to make it easier. I mean to open a file and write words which I want to search for.

For example,
word= import("> ").
**How to make it work with the code which is written below.**

```py
import requests, sys, webbrowser, bs4

res = requests.get('https://google.com/search?q='+''.join(sys.argv[1:]))
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
linkElements = soup.select('.r a')
linkToOpen = min(5, len(linkElements))
for i in range(linkToOpen):
    webbrowser.open('https://google.com'+linkElements[i].get('href'))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create **a .txt file** and put your word **line by line** into the .txt file and read with the function below, and loop through the .txt **line by line** and get result by using the prefix with the word you put into, explanation of the code is below with comment (##).

```
import requests, sys, webbrowser, bs4
##put each line into array names "lines"
lines = open("your_txt_file.txt").read().splitlines()

#loop through each line in lines
for line in lines:
    ##send link request with "line" with prefix "https://google.com/search?q="
    res = requests.get('https://google.com/search?q='+''.join(line))
    ##wait for the result
    res.raise_for_status()
    ##dump into beautifulsoup api
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
    ##get elements by selecting with soup
    linkElements = soup.select('.r a')
    ##save link to linkToOpen
    linkToOpen = min(5, len(linkElements))
    ##loop through linkToOpen and open each link
    for i in range(linkToOpen):
        webbrowser.open('https://google.com'+linkElements[i].get('href'))
```

Comment: Your program shows error: builtins.IndentationError: unexpected indent (untitled-1.py, line 2). What should I do?

Comment: Make sure all the unnecessary tabs are deleted. What are you using to run the python scrip at are you using to run the python script?

Comment: Im using wing personal 7.1

Comment: delete all the comment line, space at the beginning of each line and reinsert the tab/space for the program

Comment: It doesnt show the error anymore, but none internet page is opened